# One-time pad question (Old ciphers)

Tags: symmetric, one-time-pad

The plaintext SECRETIVE is encrypted using One Time Pad with key DDDDDDDDD. Which of the following is TRUE?

1. The ciphertext will be the same as using Caesar cipher with key of 4
2. The ciphertext is the same as the plaintext.
3. The ciphertext has 3 alphabet ‘I’.
4. The ciphertext will have 6 different unique alphabets.

This is a question from my assigment.
Please explain how you got your answer thanks :)

Comment: This is homework, thus expect only hints, and please report on your work so far and where you are stuck. It seems _alphabet_ should be changed to _letter_. Please summarize how the OTP was defined to you. The answer depends heavily on if that's with XOR of binary strings and reference to ASCII or other computer alphabet, or as extension of some Caesar cipher using modular addition over an alphabet (traditionally small) having a number of position that may not be a power of two, and thus does not allow XOR.

Comment: (Maybe this is an extension to fgrieu's comment:) According to the German Wikipedia "One-Time-Pad" is not one single encryption algorithm but it is a class or set (sorry for not knowing the correct technical jargon) of very different algorithms. Therefore the information given in your question is not enough.

Comment: Please note: [Do we accept basic level/homework questions?
Yes, we do. However, please provide an indication of what you are not understanding/need clarification on and your attempts at solving it, so we have a clear indication of where you are stuck. This goes for all questions, not just homework. **If you have just written out your assignment, your question will be closed.**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TRUE. The encryption moves every sign 4 places further.
2. FALSE. The text will changed.
3. TRUE. The 3 Es of SECRETIVE change into Is.
4. It depends on what that question actually means. There will be 6 letters that are only one there. The 7. letter, the I (resulting from the 3Es) will be three times there, so I guess the answer is true.
   This could be a more tricky question, but I doubt it because of the level the other questions have.